# Memory cache limit is not working

Tags: memory-management, cache

I have blender 3.3.1 on windows 11 and I can not manage the memory limits.

I try "memory cache limit" and "disk cache" but it seems to not work as it goes to 100% of my RAM (64GO) and finally crash.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I every body this first sentence was missing :D

Comment: Are you referring to the caching option for the video sequencer? When are you running out of memory, during playback, when rendering the output, or sometime else?

Comment: When I open large files, Blender load "things" until my PC reach 100% of RAM and then close automatically. My PC dont crash, it is still ok after blender closed.

Comment: Then your computer simply does not have enough memory to handle the particular project file. The cache settings for video sequencer do not help with this unless you are working with video files. If your project has lots of geometry and this creates the high demand on memory, then I would suggest you try to append objects from the file and try to optimized the scene step by step (reduce geometric complexity and pick less resource heavy modifier settings).

Comment: Well ok, I think we could limit memory and replace the need with disk cache. Thanks you for your time and answer :)